# MySQL - table specified twice both as a target for update and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql

When I try to execute these two queries:

```
UPDATE bills
SET id_bill_tmp = (SELECT IFNULL(id_bill_tmp, 0)+1 AS id_bill_tmp FROM bills)
WHERE id_interess = 1;

UPDATE bills
SET id_bill_tmp = (SELECT max(id_bill_tmp)+1 FROM bills)
WHERE id_interess = 1;
```

I get:

> table 'bills' is specified twice both as a target for 'update' and as
>   a separate source for data

How can I rewrite `UPDATE` to not report this error?

Comment: What is purpose of first query ? Also what you are trying to achieve please add details in your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant update the table by getting the data from the same table in a single query. For this at least you should use a temporary table or else you should go with a view

Create a view with your select query

```
CREATE VIEW `view_name` AS SELECT IFNULL(id_bill_tmp, 0)+1 AS id_bill_tmp FROM bills
```

and then update the table using the view

```
UPDATE bills
SET id_bill_tmp = (SELECT id_bill_tmp FROM view_name)
WHERE id_interess = 1;
```

Comment: Idea is good, but in last step I get `The definition of table 'view_name' prevents operation UPDATE on table 'bills'.`

Comment: Oh.. it might be because of the new version of MySQL. Then go with temp tables. Create temp table just like bills and insert bills into it. While updating bills use the value selected from the temp table. It ll surely work

Comment: What about this solution? Looks nice.

Comment: this also works well in my case. I often do the same to handle these situation.